# Did Squad 13 contain a pioneer among the Parasites?

Tags: darling-in-the-franxx

The events of episode 17 eventually lead to the revelation that

> Kokoro is pregnant with Mitsuru's child

In episode 22 New Nana states that this diagnosis was obtained primarily from old-world information regarding hormone levels. New Nana then goes on to state that pregnancy inhibits a Pistil's ability to pilot a Franxx, with the two courses of actions being:

- Stay out of the action until the child is born, or
- Abort the foetus

Which begs the question, was this the first recorded instance of a Pistil becoming pregnant? From Original Nana's flashback in episode 18 we know that

> Neither Kokoro and Mitsuru, nor Hiro and Zero Two are the first Parasite pairing to fall in love

But how is it known that pregnancy interferes with the ability to pilot a Franxx if she is the first of her kind to be affected?

Comment: The [episode wiki](http://darling-in-the-franxx.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_22#Trivia) says it's an error, as the one who is pregnant was able to pilot the Franxx in previous episodes without issue. However, the wiki does not provide a source for that

Comment: @Wondercricket I imagine physical limitations would also play a part, given the setup of the cockpit. Also keep in mind during the final time she piloted she would've been no more than a few weeks pregnant - her physical symptoms (i.e. morning sickness) didn't start to appear until after all the Parasites had been grounded following the battle for Gran Crevasse.

Comment: @Wondercricket If memory serves me correctly, she was also suffering a few sync issues during Gran Crevasse, but I'll need to double-check that.

Comment: My memory probably doesn't serve me well, so I'll need to double check as well. It's been a few week since I've watched the show. I really do like your questions though, I never really considered it beforehand

Comment: @Wondercricket A slight correction, the Franxx in question did fall into difficulties during episode 20, but that stemmed from her partner, not the pregnancy.